# How to parse "uuuu'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss;FFFFFFFFFo<Z+HHmm>" into an Instant?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, nodatime, datetime-parsing

I have this class:

```
public class Test
{
    public Instant I { get; set;}
}
```

`I` is an `Instant` because it's what makes sense semantically.

However, I have to deserialize it from this:

```
{
    "i": "2018-10-25T18:34:11.911+00:00"
}
```

and from this:

```
{
    "i": "2018-10-25T18:34:11.911+0000"
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You might want to add programming language you've used. It's not very clear from the question.

Comment: @JiriS, it's, obviously, `C#` but my question is about `json.net` and `nodatime`. I'll take answers in `C#`, `Visual Basic` or `F#`.

Comment: Is the offset always 0? If so, you could hard code that. Otherwise, the reason it's hard is that you're *trying* to lose information. Basically you have an `OffsetDateTime`, not an `Instant`. You can convert an `OffsetDateTime` to an `Instant` easily, but that does lose information. We don't make it particularly easy to do that, just like it would be relatively hard to deserialize `2018-10-26T08:19` to a `LocalDate`.

Comment: @JonSkeet, like I said, for me, it's an `Instant` because it's what made sense at the time. But I'm getting it from some service implemented in Java (it's actually 2018-10-25T18:34:11.911+0000` that I'm receiving) and I prefer to have the converter isolate my code from that then having an `2018-10-25T18:34:11.911+00:00` just because the service is using that format.

Comment: One option would be to have one representation for deserialization, then convert to a more logical representation. Or you could have one OffsetDateTime property and an Instant property that converts the OffsetDateTime property to an instant on the fly. Or if the offset is *always* 0, you should be able to use a simple InstantPattern with that hard-coded.

Comment: Is my solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53006191/402366) that bad?

Comment: Well I definitely wouldn't go via the .NET types. Will add a comment on the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach of using a `CustomInstantPattern` is a good one, but I'd avoid using any .NET date/time types at all.

Instead, I'd use two `OffsetDateTimePattern` instances, one with colons and one without, and combine them with a `CompositePattern`. You can then just delegate to that, converting to/from `Instant` when you need to.

Here's complete sample code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet;
using NodaTime.Text;
using System;
using System.Text;

class CustomInstantPattern : IPattern<Instant>
{
    private readonly IPattern<OffsetDateTime> offsetDateTimePattern;

    public CustomInstantPattern()
    {
        // Pattern explanation:
        // - o<G> means "use the G Offset pattern" (to hour, minute or second, with colons, format +00 as Z)
        // - o<I> means "use the I Offset pattern" (to hour, minute or second, without colons, format +00 as Z)
        var patternWithColon = OffsetDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("uuuu'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss;FFFFFFFFFo<G>");
        var patternWithoutColon = OffsetDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("uuuu'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss;FFFFFFFFFo<I>");
        offsetDateTimePattern = new CompositePatternBuilder<OffsetDateTime>()
        {
            // The predicates here are for formatting. As the first always
            // returns true, it doesn't really matter what the second does.
            // The intention is that some values might not be formattable with
            // all patterns, but that doesn't apply here.
            { patternWithColon, _ => true },
            { patternWithoutColon, _ => true }
        }.Build();
    }

    public StringBuilder AppendFormat(Instant value, StringBuilder builder) =>
        offsetDateTimePattern.AppendFormat(value.WithOffset(Offset.Zero), builder);

    public string Format(Instant value) =>
        offsetDateTimePattern.Format(value.WithOffset(Offset.Zero));

    public ParseResult<Instant> Parse(string text) =>
        offsetDateTimePattern.Parse(text).Convert(odt => odt.ToInstant());
}

class Entity
{
    public Instant I { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters = { new NodaPatternConverter<Instant>(new CustomInstantPattern()) }
        };
        string json = " { \"i\": \"2018-10-25T18:34:11.911+0000\" }";
        Entity entity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Entity>(json, settings);
        Console.WriteLine(entity.I);
        // Check it works with colons too
        json = " { \"i\": \"2018-10-25T18:34:11.911+00:00\" }";
        entity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Entity>(json, settings);
        Console.WriteLine(entity.I);
    }
}
```

(This has shown up two issues with Noda Time - one is that the documentation for embedded partials is incorrect for `OffsetDateTime` patterns, and one is that we don't have a standard pattern for "extended ISO" which is pretty annoying. Will try to address both when I can.)

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to work around it using a special pattern:

```
public class CustomInstantPattern : IPattern<Instant>
{
    public StringBuilder AppendFormat(Instant value, StringBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.AppendFormat("s", value.ToDateTimeOffset());
    }

    public string Format(Instant value)
    {
        return value.ToDateTimeOffset().ToString("s");
    }

    public ParseResult<Instant> Parse(string text)
    {
        try
        {
            return ParseResult<Instant>.ForValue(DateTimeOffset.Parse(text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToInstant());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ParseResult<Instant>.ForException(() => throw ex);
        }
    }
}

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
    Converters =
    {
        new NodaPatternConverter<Instant>(new CustomInstantPattern()),
    }
};

var converted = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>("{ 'I': '2018-10-25T18:34:11.911+0000'}", settings);
```

Is this the correct way?

Comment: Rather than using `DateTimeOffset.Parse`, I'd delegate to `OffsetDateTime.Parse`, as that's the Noda Time type that represents the information you've actually got. You should also be able to create a plain `InstantPattern` with a hard-coded "+00:00" part for the formatting. One point to note: your test code here uses "+0000" in the input, whereas your question shows "+00:00". Depending on the exact code, that colon could trip things up.

Comment: Once you're using `OffsetDateTime.Parse`, you can use `ParseResult.Convert` to convert a `ParseResult<OffsetDateTime>` to `ParseResult<Instant>` which will be nicer than catching an exception etc.

Comment: (If you'd like me to write all of this up as an answer, just let me know - although I'm travelling so I don't know how long it'll be before I can do so.)

Comment: I have to handle `+0000` and `+00:00`. I tried to apply an `OffsetDateTimePattern` template to an `InstantPattern`, but couldn't make it work.

Comment: If you have to handle both, that would be worth mentioning in the question. You'd need two different `OffsetDateTimePattern`s in a `CompoundPattern` - which is doable, of course. I'm still happy to write that up as an answer if you'd like me to.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I've added the two patterns to the question. Please, do write that up on an answer.